# Handle downcast error when downcasting Ref<Box<dyn Any>> into Ref<Box<T>>

Tags: rust, traits, ref, downcast, refcell

I need to write a function `foo` that takes a `&RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>`, borrows from the `RefCell` and returns a downcasted object. The downcasted type is chosen at runtime, but for this example let's assume it's `usize`.

```
use core::any::Any;
use std::cell::{RefCell, Ref};

pub fn foo<T: 'static>(cell: &RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) -> Option<Ref<Box<T>>> {
    ???
}

pub fn main() {

    let boxed: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(1 as usize);
    let cell = RefCell::new(boxed);

    let num = foo(&cell);
    println!("x: {}", num.unwrap());
}
```

I tried implementing `foo` like this:

```
// 1:
pub fn foo<T: 'static>(cell: &RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) -> Option<Ref<Box<T>>> {
    let borrowed_cell = Ref::map(cell.borrow(), |borrow| borrow.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap());
    Some(borrowed_cell)
}
```

The problem with this version is that it assumes that `downcast_ref` will always work, but I would like to catch a `downcast_ref` error.
Below I try to implement `foo` in a way that I can catch the error:

```
// 2:
pub fn foo<T: 'static>(cell: &RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) -> Option<Ref<T>> {
    {
        cell.borrow().downcast_ref::<T>()?;
    }

    let borrowed_cell = Ref::map(cell.borrow(), |borrow| borrow.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap());
    Some(borrowed_cell)
}
```

This version can catch the downcast error, but it has to call `downcast_ref` twice (which could be acceptable, but I am wondering if there is a better way). When trying to use `downcast_ref` only once, I got stuck with lifetime errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering with it, I came up with this solution. You can make use of `Any::is<T>()` to check the borrow before mapping it.

```rust
pub fn foo<T: 'static>(cell: &RefCell<Box<dyn Any>>) -> Option<Ref<T>> {
    let borrowed = cell.borrow();
    
    if borrowed.is::<T>() {
        Some(Ref::map(borrowed, |x| x.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()))
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Rust Playground [link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c991e676d5ab45bb218dcd2a887d06ed)

Comment: That's it, thanks! Just another question related to the first one: let's say I want to call a function `bar` that, like `downcast_ref`, returns an option. How would I propagate the `Option` out of the closure of `Ref::map`, as in this case we don't have a function like `is::<T>` to call before?

Comment: Found this [crate](https://docs.rs/crate/ref_filter_map/1.0.1), this seems to be what I'm looking for.